# How to detect installed Chrome version from my Android App?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am working on a feature where I need to transition user from Android Native APP to Chrome custom tab only if chrome version installed on the device is greater than version 65. So my question is, is there a way we can detect chrome version from Android Native App ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
private boolean isChromeInstalledAndVersionGreaterThan65() {
    PackageInfo pInfo;
    try {
        pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.android.chrome", 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        //chrome is not installed on the device
        return false;
    }
    if (pInfo != null) {
        //Chrome has versions like 68.0.3440.91, we need to find the major version
        //using the first dot we find in the string
        int firstDotIndex = pInfo.versionName.indexOf(".");
        //take only the number before the first dot excluding the dot itself
        String majorVersion = pInfo.versionName.substring(0, firstDotIndex);
        return Integer.parseInt(majorVersion) > 65;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> Obviously this will work until Chrome will be versioned how they did until now, if they will decide to change the versioning the logic should be updated as well. (I don't think this will happen but for max safety put everything in a try-catch)

If targeting API 30 or above don't forget to add the Chrome package to the list of the one you want to query in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.android.chrome" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" /> in the manifest file. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62345806/5399102

Comment: @RajibBiswas you don't need that permission, it is too wide just for this small check. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    private boolean checkVersion(String uri) {
            String versionName;
            int version = 0;
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            try {
                versionName = pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).versionName;
                String[] split = versionName.split(Pattern.quote("."));
                String major = split[0];
                version = Integer.parseInt(major);
                return version > 65;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                //Catch the Exception
            }
            return false;
}
```

Then call above method using

```
checkVersion("com.android.chrome"); //This will return a boolean value
```